# HTML div in div

Tags: html, css, xhtml

please look at my code and say me why the div "bildunterschrift" doesn´t displays in the "bild" div.It´s always outside the parent-div in the right edge of the complete screen. I wanna have the div "bildunterschrift" in the right corner of the "bild" div.

**My code:**

```
<!--HTML code-->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CSS3: Bild mit Bildbeschriftung</title>
<link href="design2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>

<h1>CSS3: Bild mit Beschriftung <i>via</i> CSS3</h1>

<div id="bild">

<div id="bildunterschrift">
    Hundewelpe
</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>    



/* CSS code */

#bild
{
background-color:hsla(0,100%,0%,1);
height:340px;
width:320px;
}
#bildunterschrift
{
height:40px;
width:320px;
color:hsla(0,0%,0%,0.8);
background-color:hsla(90,100%,60%,1);
position:absolute;
right:0px;
bottom:0px;
font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: what about `top:0` ?

Comment: You have positioned it `absolute`. positioning the element to the first parent with `position: relative`.

Comment: @Benjamin then the div "bildunterschrift" is in the right edge of the complete screen. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `#bild`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cue0byxL/)**

```
#bild {
    background-color:hsla(0, 100%, 0%, 1);
    height:340px;
    width:320px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change like this and try:
`#bildunterschrift`
`{`
`margin-top:295px;`

`height:40px;`

`width:320px;`

`color:hsla(0,0%,0%,0.8);`

`background-color:hsla(90,100%,60%,1);`

`float:right;`

`right:0px;`

`bottom:0px;`

`font-size:30px;`

`}`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
#bild {

  background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 0%, 1);

  height: 340px;

  width: 320px;

  position: relative;

}

#bildunterschrift {

  height: 40px;

  width: 320px;

  color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);

  background-color: hsla(90, 100%, 60%, 1);

  position: absolute;

  right: 0px;

  bottom: 0px;

  font-size: 30px;

}
```

```html
<h1>CSS3: Bild mit Beschriftung <i>via</i> CSS3</h1>

<div id="bild">

  <div id="bildunterschrift">
    Hundewelpe
  </div>

</div>
```